# ¿Cómo hacer un conteo de un select con excepciones?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excepciones

¿Cómo podría hacer un conteo de esta consulta?, quisiera que me muestre el conteo de todos los datos seleccionados. Aquí hay 32 datos, y quisiera que muestre como en un COUNT(*):

```
SELECT cu.idespecialidad,es.Nombre,convert(char(5),cu.horainicio, 108) as HoraInicio,convert(char(5),cu.horafin, 108) as HoraFin FROM cupos cu
inner join Especialidades es on es.IdEspecialidad = cu.idespecialidad
EXCEPT
SELECT ci.IdEspecialidad,ci.HoraInicio,ci.HoraFin,ess.Nombre FROM Citas ci
inner join Especialidades ess on ess.IdEspecialidad = ci.idespecialidad
EXCEPT
SELECT es1.IdEspecialidad,cb.HoraInicio,cb.HoraFin,es1.Nombre FROM CitasBloqueadas cb
inner join Especialidades es1 on es1.Nombre = cb.Especialidad
```

Comment: ¿Y que es lo que quieres contar? ¿la cantidad de filas?, ¿la cantidad de valores de cada columna?

Comment: Lo que quiero es es me muestre en una columna el conteo y en la otra columna el nombre de las especialidades

Cuando uso esta consulta:
SELECT count(idespecialidad) AS conteo,idespecialidad FROM cupos GROUP BY idespecialidad

Me sale como quiero, pero quiero que funcione con la consulta que deje arriba

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar una CTE (Common Table Expression https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
WITH TablaCTE AS (
    SELECT cu.idespecialidad,
            es.Nombre,convert(char(5),cu.horainicio, 108) as HoraInicio,
            convert(char(5),cu.horafin, 108) as HoraFin,
            es.Nombre
    FROM cupos cu
    inner join Especialidades es on es.IdEspecialidad = cu.idespecialidad
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ci.IdEspecialidad,
            ci.HoraInicio,
            ci.HoraFin,
            ess.Nombre 
    FROM Citas ci
    inner join Especialidades ess on ess.IdEspecialidad = ci.idespecialidad
    EXCEPT
    SELECT es1.IdEspecialidad,
            cb.HoraInicio,
            cb.HoraFin,
            es1.Nombre 
    FROM CitasBloqueadas cb
    inner join Especialidades es1 on es1.Nombre = cb.Especialidad
)
SELECT count(idespecialidad), idespecialidad
FROM TablaCTE
GROUP BY idespecialidad;
```

La otra opción es que lleves el resultado de tu consulta a una tabla temporal y sobre esa tabla temporal se haga el mismo cálculo del count

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar asi

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT cu.idespecialidad,es.Nombre,convert(char(5),cu.horainicio, 108) as HoraInicio,convert(char(5),cu.horafin, 108) as HoraFin FROM cupos cu
inner join Especialidades es on es.IdEspecialidad = cu.idespecialidad
EXCEPT
SELECT ci.IdEspecialidad,ci.HoraInicio,ci.HoraFin,ess.Nombre FROM Citas ci
inner join Especialidades ess on ess.IdEspecialidad = ci.idespecialidad
EXCEPT
SELECT es1.IdEspecialidad,cb.HoraInicio,cb.HoraFin,es1.Nombre FROM CitasBloqueadas cb
inner join Especialidades es1 on es1.Nombre = cb.Especialidad)
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], una explicación no estaría de mas